# My VBA loop is not starting at the beginning of a subfolder in Outlook

Tags: vba, loops, outlook

I have the below code that runs through a folder looking for unread messages from a specific person with a specific subject. The loop is not beginning at the most recent emails. It's beginning a month ago where all the messages are read.

```
Sub MovingAttachmentsIntoNetworkFolders()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Email Subfolder") 'Specify Folder here

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

For Each Item In olFolder.Items
    Debug.Print Item.ReceivedTime
    If Item.UnRead = True Then
        If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
            Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem: Set oMail = Item

            Debug.Print Item.SenderEmailAddress
            Debug.Print Item.Subject
            Debug.Print Item.Attachments.Count

            If Item.Sender = "emailaddress@email.com" And _
            Item.Subject = "EmailSubject" And _
            Item.Attachments.Count = 1 Then
            'Set folder to save in.
                Dim olDestFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
                Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
                Dim Att As String

            'location to save in.  Can be root drive or mapped network drive.
                Const attPath As String = "mappednetworkdrive"

            ' save attachment
                Set myAttachments = Item.Attachments
                Att = myAttachments.Item(1).FileName
                Debug.Print Att & "\" & Format(Item.ReceivedTime, "mm-dd-yyyy")
                myAttachments.Item(1).SaveAsFile Format(Item.ReceivedTime, "mm.dd.yyyy") & " " & Att

            ' mark as read
                Item.UnRead = False
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next

ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit

End Sub
```

Any reason why my code is behaving this way?

Comment: What are the results of your `Debug.Print` statements? Can you run the Procedure and Copy/Paste immediate window text in here?
As a side note, you may find it helpful to include a timestamp in your `Debug.Print` statement (`Debug.Print now(),Variable1, Variable2`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Email data exported to Excel - Sort by Received Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948295/email-data-exported-to-excel-sort-by-received-date)

Comment: You get one question per post. Create a new question for the skipped save and edit to remove it from this one.

Comment: The Debug.Print statements show correct information, the right email address, the correct subject, and the correct number of attachments but it's as if the code is saying they are failing. I triple checked spelling and format for each of the IF statement requirements.

Comment: Why do you expect the Items collection to be sorted in any particular way? It will only be sorted when you explicitly call Items.Sort.

Comment: I am assuming the loop is reading the items in chronological order based on the debug outputs for Received Time. `9/26/2017 3:36:31 PM 
9/26/2017 3:23:32 PM 
9/26/2017 3:14:50 PM 
9/26/2017 3:03:37 PM 
9/26/2017 2:52:16 PM 
9/26/2017 2:52:11 PM 
9/26/2017 2:52:08 PM 
9/26/2017 1:57:59 PM 
9/26/2017 1:24:07 PM 
9/26/2017 12:32:18 PM 
9/26/2017 11:48:41 AM 
9/26/2017 10:29:33 AM ` @DmitryStreblechenko

Comment: No, once again, do not expect any particular order. You can rely on an order if and only if you previously called Sort on the same instance  of the Items object.

Comment: So is there a way to find the default order of the loop? The debug shows that it appears to be in chronological descending order, just starting at the wrong date @DmitryStreblechenko

Comment: Why are you stuck on the default (whatever that is) order? It is implementation specific and most likely the order in which the items are created, which is not the same as the received date. Just read the MAPIFolder.Items into a separate variable, call Items.Sort, then loop through the items. MOre than that, you should never process all items in a folder - call Items.Restrict or Items.Find/FindNext first wit the appropriate restriction ("[UnRead] = True" in your case).

Comment: I added the sort to the code and it did not solve the problem. I'm focused on the loop order because obviously something is not behaving as intended. I did add the "[Unread] = True" part and that actually seems to have solved my problem. Thank you for your help @DmitryStreblechenko

Comment: Show your updated code. Make sure you are working with only one instance of the Items object instead of calling MAPIFolder.Items every time (which will return a brand new Items object every time)

Answer (score 0):

For a For Each loop, you can sort a collection of the items in the folder by ReceivedTime as described here [Email data exported to Excel - Sort by Received Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948295/email-data-exported-to-excel-sort-by-received-date)

Note: Untested code to demonstrate how to sort

```
Option Explicit

Sub MovingAttachmentsIntoNetworkFolders()

Dim objNS As NameSpace
Dim olFolder As Folder

dim objItem as object
dim fldItems as items

Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

'Specify Folder here
Set olFolder = olFolder.Folders("Email Subfolder")

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948295/email-data-exported-to-excel-sort-by-received-date
set fldItems = olFolder.Items
fldItems.Sort "ReceivedTime", true

For Each objItem In fldItems
    Debug.Print objItem.ReceivedTime
    If objItem.UnRead = True Then
        If TypeOf objItem Is MailItem Then

            Debug.Print objItem.SenderEmailAddress
            Debug.Print objItem.Subject
            Debug.Print objItem.Attachments.Count

            If objItem.Sender = "emailaddress@email.com" And _
              objItem.Subject = "EmailSubject" And _
              objItem.Attachments.Count = 1 Then

                ' mark as read
                objItem.UnRead = False
            End If
        End If
    End If
    set objItem = Nothing
Next

ProgramExit:
    Set objNS = Nothing
    Set olFolder = Nothing
    set fldItems = Nothing
    set objItem = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ProgramExit

End Sub
```

If code is in Outlook there is no need to reference Outlook.

Avoid using Item and olMail for variable names as they already have a purpose.

Comment: I saw this solution on here and it did not work. It's as if the loop is ignoring that line as soon as it is executed. The only thing I can think of is that i had my hard drive replaced on that date so something might be triggering it to start there instead of the most recent emails. @niton

Comment: If the collection is sorted the wrong way around then `fldItems.Sort "ReceivedTime", false`  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/items-sort-method-outlook