# Import Outlook Emails to Excel Oldest to Newest for a Specified Date Range

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, email, outlook

I am trying to make an excel macro to import emails from my outlook folder into an excel file for a specified date range (of received emails). This process must be done on a regular basis. Hence, I need to go on adding the emails below the existing emails in the excel sheet.

In my sheet- cell **L1** contains **From date** and cell **L2** contains **To date**.

My mailbox is sorted from **Oldest to Newest**. I have emails from 2019 till date. My first email is from 27/08/2019.

I want to fetch emails that for the range 28/08/2020 to 30/08/2020. Cell L1 has 28/08/2020. Cell L2 has 30/08/2020.

Below is the code that I used. The macro exits the loop without doing anything. I tried **single stepping through** the code and found that the macro exits the loop immediately after the first email.

I think I am missing something in the logic.

Also, rather than instructing the user to have their mailbox sorted from oldest to newest, can we force the VBA to do that? I tried `OutlookItems.Sort [ReceivedTime]`, true but got the error "Object Required". Now I have made it a comment in the code. How can I add that into this code?

```
Sub Download_Emails()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim OutlookMail As Variant
Dim objOwner As Outlook.Recipient
Dim i As Integer
Dim olItems As Object
Dim olItem As Object
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ToDt As Date

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

ToDt = Range("L2").Value + 1

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objOwner = OutlookNamespace.CreateRecipient("xxxxxxxxxx.com")   'Set the Outlook mailbox name
objOwner.Resolve

'OutlookItems.Sort [ReceivedTime], true (results in error Object required)

'Allows the user to select the desired folder from which the emails are to be imported
If objOwner.Resolved Then
Set Folder = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").PickFolder
End If

i = LastRow
LastRow = LastRow + 1


For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
If TypeName(OutlookMail) = "MailItem" Then

'Sets the date from which the user wants to import the emails from
If CDate(OutlookMail.ReceivedTime) < Range("L1").Value Then   'From Date
    'Do nothing
    
ElseIf CDate(OutlookMail.ReceivedTime) < ToDt Then   'To Date

'Imports email subject, received date and time, sender's name, and the email body into the excel file
Range("A1").Offset(i, 0) = OutlookMail.Subject
Range("B1").Offset(i, 0) = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
Range("C1").Offset(i, 0) = OutlookMail.SenderName
'Range("D1").Offset(i, 0) = OutlookMail.Body
               
i = i + 1

'If the email date range is crossed, then exit the loop
Else: Exit For
End If
End If

Next OutlookMail
 
Set Folder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing
 
'Do not wrap text of the imported emails
Sheet1.Cells.WrapText = False
 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Pop up saying the import is complete
MsgBox "Email importing is done!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, put a breakpoint on the first test, "if CDate(...received time) < L1 value". Put another breakpoint on  the second test "ElseIf CDate(...received time) < ToDt". Then run and after break point is hit, during single stepping, by moving the mouse over `ReceivedTime` in the first test, what the received time is of the email. Then check again with the mouse what value `Range("L1").Value` has. What are the values? As you have older emails than L1 indicates, it should then proceed to `Next OutlookMail` and repeat the loop for a couple of emails. (cont.....)

Comment: Then remove the first breakpoint and see if you reach the second one (at `ElseIf...`). Again, make notes about the received time and `ToDt`. What are they? How does the program proceed from there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Email data exported to Excel - Sort by Received Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948295/email-data-exported-to-excel-sort-by-received-date)

Comment: I checked. At the first check breakpoint, `ReceivedTime` does not show anything. Does not even say empty; just nothing shows up when I hover the mouse pointer on it.  `Range("L1").Value` shows 28/08/2020. Further, program goes to second check and then immediately goes to `Else: Exit For`.

First breakpoint removed. Program passes through the first check. At the second check, `ReceivedTime` does not show anything, `ToDt` shows 31/08/2020. Program proceeds to `Else: Exit For`. I guess it never goes to the second email.

Comment: I'm sorry, my directions where incorrect, in that you don't see the `CDate(OutlookMail.ReceivedTime)` with the mouse. But you can add it as a Watch in the Watches window. Btw, I just made a test with my Outlook and it correctly, 1) omits emails before L1, 2) copies the info from emails from the selected date range L1..L2, and 3) exits the loop when the first email after L2 is hit.

Comment: Btw, this sounds nasty: *Also, rather than instructing the user to have their mailbox sorted from oldest to newest, can we force the VBA to do that?* I would send any piece of software, that thinks it knows better than I how my mailbox should sorted, to the waste bin.

Comment: Very strange that the code doesn't work for me! I tried choosing different folders from my inbox just to be sure that there is no issue with one particular folder, but the program behaves the same- exits the loop after first email. As of now I will park this aside. Since importing newest to oldest works fine for me, for the time being I will adjust the macro to sort the imported emails based on the date received. Many thanks Tom for taking time in trying to solve this for me!

Comment: Perhaps the first mail has a date later than L2, that would explain the problem. That is why I asked you to debug the execution and **check the actual date time values** of the mails, as the program sees them.

Comment: No, The first mail is from 27/08/2019 and L2 has date 30/08/2020. I also tried in Watch window for both the conditions. The value it shows is  **<Out of context>**, I don't know if I did it correctly since it was my first time.

Comment: The Watches view shows <Out of context> when the program is running, but *shows the watch value when the program stops on a breakpoint*. Did you have any breakpoint set as I have said? Sometimes I also had to click the watches when program stopped at the breakpoint, to get them to display the values.

Comment: I tried. For both the logical conditions. At **Break when value is true** - Nothing happens, program continues and exits the loop. At **Break when value changes** - Program stops at `If TypeName(OutlookMail) = "MailItem" Then` and **Watch value** is **False**. If I continue to run it, it exits the loop.

Comment: You can set a breakpoint by clicking in the left margin beside the line where you want to single step. A dark maroon colored dot indicates a set breakpoint. You can then step one line at a time with F8. I got the impression you have single stepped through the code, ergo know how to do it?

Comment: Yes, I know applying breakpoint, and stepping through the program. I tried that. Even then, both at the first and second condition, the Watch value shows False.

Comment: And what is the date/time (in the running code) of the message that makes the loop end? How many times must I ask this. **It is not necessarily the date/time of the first message in the mailbox.**

Comment: It might be better for you to send a debug output to the "Immediate" panel of the IDE. Add a line: `Debug.Print CDate(OutlookMail.ReceivedTime)` immediately before the first check (`If CDate(OutlookMail.ReceivedTime) < Range("L1").Value`) and then tell me what values you get there.

Comment: Debug.print for the first condition shows date **26/08/2021 20:53:18** in the Immediate panel. Oldest email in my mailbox is from 27/08/1019 and the newest from 26/08/2021 20:53:18. My mailbox is sorted from Oldest to Newest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236514/discussion-between-tom-brunberg-and-seema).

Answer (score 1):

If your first encountered email date is past your dates range, your code goes to `Else: Exit For` and the loop ends.
Just remove this line of code.

And a word about sorting `for each` loop does not guarantee any order of items and sorting them prior to executing your code would probably not affect the order they are returned by the loop.

EDIT: you did not declare `OutlookItems` nor assigned any value to it - this is the reason you get an error, best practice is to always place `Option Explicit` at the top of your code or force it in settings.

Comment: `ToDt` is initialized soon after the dims.

Comment: my bad, but the main point remains, there is something wrong with the dates as the code works, I will edit the answer

Comment: @avb, Thanks for taking time to analyse.

Comment: @TomBrunberg if it is removed, emails not within given range still will not be imported but the loop will continue

Comment: You are quite right. In a previous case it was specifically requested.

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely on the right avenue. Iterating over all items in the folder is not really a good idea. Instead, you need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the Items class. Read more about them in the following series of articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

If you need to search for items in multiple folders you may consider using the `AdvancedSearch` method of the Application class. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The Restrict and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

Read more about the AdvancedSearch method in the [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) article.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to great help that I got- I modified the codes to retrieve Outlook emails from oldest to newest. Posting the answer so that it could be of use to someone in the future.

```
Download_Emails()

Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim olMail As Variant
Dim objOwner As Outlook.Recipient
Dim i As Integer
Dim olItems As Outlook.Items
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ToDt As Date

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

ToDt = Range("L2").Value + 1

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objOwner = OutlookNamespace.CreateRecipient("xxxxxxxxxx.com")   'Set the Outlook mailbox name
objOwner.Resolve

'Allows the user to select the desired folder from which the emails are to be imported
If objOwner.Resolved Then
Set Folder = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").PickFolder

'Sorts the inbox from Oldest to Newest 
Set olItems = Folder.Items
olItems.Sort "ReceivedTime", False 
End If

i = LastRow
LastRow = LastRow + 1

For Each olMail In olItems
If TypeName(olMail) = "MailItem" Then

'Sets the date from which the user wants to import the emails from
If CDate(olMail.ReceivedTime) < Range("L1").Value Then
'Do nothing

ElseIf CDate(olMail.ReceivedTime) < ToDt Then

'Imports email subject, received date and time, sender's name, and email body into excel file
Range("A1").Offset(i, 0) = olMail.Subject
Range("B1").Offset(i, 0) = olMail.ReceivedTime
Range("C1").Offset(i, 0) = olMail.SenderName
'Range("D1").Offset(i, 0) = olMail.Body
              
i = i + 1

'If the email date range is crossed, then exit the loop
Else: Exit For
End If
End If

Next olMail

Set Folder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
'Do not wrap text of the imported emails
Sheet1.Cells.WrapText = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Pop up saying the import is complete
MsgBox "Emails imported!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation

End If

End Sub
```